# feel 'me' inside what should i do for the next step

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-effects

I have two times experience where first time i am doing my sitting meditation. I was so calm i feel like i was 'trap inside the body(don't know how to explain)' i can feel that i was deep 'inside there'. by that time i cannot feel my breathing or heard any sounds from outside. I can 'feel/see' my body from inside.

second experience- when i was walking home from work. i guess i was too concentrating while walking. Again i can feel i was again 'inside'(different from the first experience) and i can see(not using my eye) it clearly that my 'leg' is moving 'by itself'. My eyes was open when i walk but i feel like i am not seeing 'my leg' using my eyes.It's a bit freak me out but i was very calm at that time.

Anyone out there please kindly help me what should i do when i face this problem again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As your meditation progresses you will feel sensations both inside and outside, which was covered more in detail in an earlier [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/21187/295). These sensations depend on Fabrications which manifest itself as pleasant, unpleasant or neutral. As you meditate you might get blissful feeling. Do not get attached to them or dwell too much on the experience.

Also the breath is bodily fabrication. When you meditate you bodily fabrication will calm down. Your breath will become so subtle that you might not feel it.

Mostly when you see inside your body or this can be just imagination, through if you develop supernormal powers you will be able to do this. In the case you feel inside and outside it is a different case. When this happens you should keep looking until you see arising and passing throughout your body, i.e., you see your whole material body is in a flux of change.

Finally do not dwell too much on meditative experiences because you can get carried away and get attached or perhaps averse to them. You have to keep and unattached and clear mind to see things as they are. I.e., you have to keep your mind equanimity at all times.